# Karate API - Is there a limit on test loads? Error - "The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye"

Tags: testing, karate

I have a scenario whereby I need to test 94000 Dashboards responses. I have separated them into 2 feature files like the one below.

Is there a better way of handling these tests?

```
Scenario Outline: Get Dashboards
    Given path 'graphql'
    And request
    """
        {
          query: '#(query)',
            variables: {
            limit: <limit>,
            offset: <offset>
          }
        }
    """
    And method POST
    Then status 200
    And match each response.data.Dashboard[*] == expectedResponse
    And match response.data.Dashboard == '#[<total>]'

    Examples:
      | limit | offset   |  total |
      | 2000  | 62000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 64000    |  2000  |  
      | 2000  | 66000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 68000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 70000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 72000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 74000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 76000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 78000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 80000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 82000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 84000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 86000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 88000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 90000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 92000    |  2000  |
      | 2000  | 94000    |  1381  |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a ["dynamic" `Scenario Outline`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline) in the following ways:

- JSON array
- CSV file
- JS function, e.g: like [this example](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/blob/main/src/test/java/app/api/data/outline-setup-function.feature)

The advantage of the `Scenario Outline` is that it splits each row into a separate test and would try to run it on parallel threads as well. You may have better results instead of trying to have Karate parse 94000 items within a `Feature` file.

If that doesn't work, use the [Gatling integration](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling) along with a [Feeder](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#feeders). We have teams report that they successfully used it to speed up "bulk" cases like this.

Comment: In my code example I am using a Scenario Outline though, am I missing something? I'm not sure how a js function would handle this better. Perhaps Gatling but that would be my last resort.

Comment: @MarkHughes you have hard coded rows within a feature file, the options here split it into a separate json object or function. sorry I can't be more clear than this, please read the links